# Holes in ElementMesh with ToElementMesh of ImplicitRegion

Tags: plotting, finite-element-method, mesh, implicit

I am trying to plot a function in a region below a level curve of the function and within a cell. I have been doing this by calculating an `ElementMesh` using `ImplicitRegion` and `ToElementMesh`, but the result is inaccurate.

Here is the cell (it's just a square),

```
cell = Parallelogram[{-0.5`, -0.5`}, {{1.`, 0.`}, {0.`, 1.`}}];
Graphics[{Transparent, EdgeForm[Thick], cell}]
```

and the function,

```
f[kx_, ky_, n_] := 
  Sort[Eigenvalues[{{(-1. + kx)^2 + (-1. + ky)^2, -0.23, 0., -0.23, 
       0.12, 0., 0., 0., 
       0.}, {-0.23, (-1. + kx)^2 + (0. + ky)^2, -0.23, 0.12, -0.23, 
       0.12, 0., 0., 0.}, {0., -0.23, (-1. + kx)^2 + (1. + ky)^2, 0., 
       0.12, -0.23, 0., 0., 0.}, {-0.23, 0.12, 
       0., (0. + kx)^2 + (-1. + ky)^2, -0.23, 0., -0.23, 0.12, 
       0.}, {0.12, -0.23, 
       0.12, -0.23, (0. + kx)^2 + (0. + ky)^2, -0.23, 0.12, -0.23, 
       0.12}, {0., 0.12, -0.23, 0., -0.23, (0. + kx)^2 + (1. + ky)^2, 
       0., 0.12, -0.23}, {0., 0., 0., -0.23, 0.12, 
       0., (1. + kx)^2 + (-1. + ky)^2, -0.23, 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 
       0.12, -0.23, 
       0.12, -0.23, (1. + kx)^2 + (0. + ky)^2, -0.23}, {0., 0., 0., 
       0., 0.12, -0.23, 0., -0.23, (1. + kx)^2 + (1. + ky)^2}}]][[
   n]];
Plot3D[f[x, y, 4], {x, y} \[Element] cell, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

and what the region should look like,

```
isovalue = 1.29897233417072;
ContourPlot[f[x, y, 4], {x, y} \[Element] cell, 
 Contours -> {isovalue}, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, 
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

This is what I have tried

```
reg = ToElementMesh[
   ImplicitRegion[
    f[x, y, 4] < isovalue && {x, y} \[Element] cell, {x, y}], 
   "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.01, MeshQualityGoal -> 1, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01, 
   "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> "Continuation"];
RegionPlot[reg]
```

[image]
The region is no more accurate when I decrease `MaxCellMeasure` or `MaxBoundaryCellMeasure`. I also tried the solution suggested [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183630/elementmesh-from-implicitregion-cuts-corners-of-region).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another approach is:

```
reg = ToElementMesh[
   ImplicitRegion[
    f[x, y, 4] < isovalue && {x, y} \[Element] cell, {x, y}], 
   "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.01, MeshQualityGoal -> 1, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01, 
   "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> {"RegionPlot", "SamplePoints" -> 41}];

reg["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

One thing to be a bit careful about is the question if the holes intersect the boundary. From the mesh it does not look like it but the math might say it.

Answer (score 5):

I hope I interpreted your question correctly that you want a more accurate `ElementMesh` representation of the region.

First we create a high quality `Graphics` of the region of interest.

```
isovalue = 1.29897233417072;
(* Add some margins to plot range to get connected region. *)
tolerance = 0.05;
plot = ContourPlot[
  f[x, y, 4],
  {x, y} ∈ Cuboid[{-0.5, -0.5} - tolerance, {0.5, 0.5} + tolerance],
  Contours -> {isovalue},
  ColorFunction -> GrayLevel,
  (* We need high quality plot for ImageMesh later. *)
  PlotPoints -> 200,
  Frame -> None
]
```

Create `MeshRegion` from `Graphics` object.

```
mreg = ImageMesh[ColorNegate[plot]]
```

And convert it to `ElementMesh`.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[mreg,"MeshOrder"->1]
(* ElementMesh[{{7., 353.}, {7., 353.}}, {TriangleElement["<" 1057 ">"]}] *)

mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image: mesh]